# Chrome Web Store: how to check for Payment with google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, chrome-web-store

We put two Google Apps Script web services succesfully into the chrome web store. One is f.e.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aagmbfbgdjhkilafppdjihnafgcahpbc

Now we want to check for Payment like described in
https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/check_for_payment?hl=de

But
1. How to get a user ID for the current user (an OpenID URL corresponding to a Google account)
2. How to make a request with the Licensing API
with Google Apps Script code?

Answer (score 0):

Do you just use the verify payment method:

```
    google.payments.inapp.getPurchases({
  'success': onLicenseUpdate,
  'failure': onLicenseUpdateFail
});
```

responds with:

```
    {
  "response": {
    "details": [
      {
        "kind": "chromewebstore#payment",
        "itemId": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
        "sku": "giant_tv",
        "createdTime": "1387221267248",
        "state": "ACTIVE"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/payments-iap